# How to fix conditional jump?

Tags: c, while-loop, valgrind, singly-linked-list, getchar

I have a problem with, i think, function INPUT. But i can't understand how to fix it
[functions code]

```
typedef struct Item {
    int data; 
    struct Item* next;
} Item;

typedef struct Queue{ 
    Item* head;
    Item* tail;
} Queue;


void input(Queue* list,int* stroka) {
     Item* new = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item));
    new->data = *stroka;
    new->next = NULL;
    if (!list->head) {
        list->head = new;
        list->tail = new;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = new;
        list->tail = new;
    }
}  
  int main() {
    int stroka;
    Queue* list = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    while(stroka != EOF) {
        stroka = getchar();
        input(list, &stroka);
    }
    printf("\n");
    print(list);
}
```

[valgrind message]

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29969==    at 0x10931A: input ()
==29969==    by 0x1093CF: main ()
==29969==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==29969==    at 0x48427B5: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==29969==    by 0x1093B1: main ()
```

tried to change some blocks of code but i didn't come to anything

Comment: Its telling you that you never initialize the queue you allocated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `while(stroka != EOF)` What is `stroka` supposed to contain when you first come here? Does your compiler mention something about using `stroka` without assigning any value first? You probably wanted to use `do {} while ()` instead of `while(){}`.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you provide a pointer to int to `input` function? Why not just provide the int value itself?

Comment: Queue* list = (Queue*)calloc(1,sizeof(Queue));
this works correctly, but there are still problems with leaks

Comment: "*there are still problems with leaks*" -- well, yes and no.  You dynamically allocate your `Queue` (which seems unnecessary) and the `Item`s, and you do not free them before the program exits.  Valgrind will report this, as memory that is unfreed but still reachable.  Strictly speaking, that's not a leak, and not a significant problem.  But if you need to attain a completely clean report from Valgrind then free those objects before terminating.

Answer (score 3):

In the while loop you are using an uninitialized object of the type `int` and trying it to compare with a null pointer

```
int stroka;
Queue* list = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
while(stroka != EOF) {
    stroka = getchar();
    input(list, &stroka);
}
```

that does not make sense.

And there is no need to allocate dynamically an object of the type `Queue`.

Also instead of `getchar` it is much better to use `scanf` to enter integers instead of single characters that will be interpreted as integers including the new line character `'\n'`..

Also there is no any sense to pass the object `stroke` through a pointer to the function.

The function should be declared and defined the following way

```
int input( Queue* list, int data ) 
{
    Item *new_item = malloc( sizeof( *new_item ) );
    int success = new_item != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_item->data = data;
        new_item->next = NULL;

        if ( list->head == NULL ) 
        {
            list->head = new_item;
        } 
        else 
        {
            list->tail->next = new_item;
        }

        list->tail = new_item;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And in main you can write for example

```
  int main( void ) 
  {
    Queue list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

    for ( int data; scanf( "%d", &data ) == 1; )
    {
        input( &list, data );
    }

    printf("\n");
    print(list);
}
```

If you want to enter characters then declare the function like

```
int input( Queue* list, char data );
```

and in main write

```
    for ( char data; scanf( " %c", &data ) == 1; )
    {
        input( &list, data );
    }
```

Pay attention to the space in the format string in the call of `scanf`. It allows to skip white space characters.

And do not forget to write a function that will free all the allocated memory when the list will nit be required any more.